Files moved from linux into Samba share on same server are invisible to others
This is a rocky linux 9.0 server running a service that receives files from a gateway. The service moves the files to a folder which is shared with samba. These files are not visible on the samba share when connecting from a windows server.
I have been troubleshooting this a couple of days now and this is what I have found.
Files moved from within the file system no matter which user or group have created them is not visible on the share. I have tried to set the setgid bit and setfacl command to make files inherit group permission but that is not working.
The service which receives files is putting the files there with 0600. Not that it matters because making a file with root on another place in the file system and changing owners to root:sambagroup and chmod to 777 before moving it into the share folder is not working either.
Trying to use chmod or chown directly on the file after moving or copying it in is not working. Still invisible.
Files created directly with winscp, either creating it with it or copying in from another server works. Creating files with the touch command directly on the share folder are also visible.
I can also create and drop files onto the share from windows.
Is it a samba problem or an underlying OS problem? How can I fix this?
Here is the smb.conf:
       [global]
            server string = Samba Server %v
            netbios name = MYSERVER
            security = user
            dns proxy = no
            server min protocol = SMB3
            server max protocol = SMB3
            client min protocol = SMB3
            client max protocol = SMB3
    
       [sambashare]
            path = /srv/samba/sambashare/
            valid users = @sambagrp
            guest ok = no
            writable = yes
            browsable = yes


I've not much experiences with rocky Linux, but maybe your troubles are caused by a wrongly configured SELinux. SELinux is an additional security layer. You find more information here: https://docs.rockylinux.org/guides/security/learning_selinux/
